# Javascript code not working on PHP include

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, dictionary, include

So I have a main page which have buttons, each buttons contain names, when I click that button I want to pop up div which shows information of that person, I used ajax to retrieve info from php,

```
var strURL="searchSender.php?ID="+ID;
var req = getXMLHTTP();
if (req) {          
    req.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (req.readyState == 4) {
            // only if "OK"
            if (req.status == 200) {
                outMsg=req.responseText;
                var prevWin = document.getElementById("senderInfo");
                prevWin.innerHTML = outMsg;
                prevWin.style.top = 50+"px";
                prevWin.style.right = 80+"px";
                prevWin.style.visibility = "visible";
            } else {
                alert("Problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
            }
        }               
    }           
    req.open("GET", strURL, true);
    req.send(null);
}
```

searchSender.php basically redeem info of that specific person from the database, that returns these codes (i didn't include here the code that retrieves data from database)

```
<label>Name: <?php echo $row['Name'];?> </label></br>
<label>Address: <?php echo $row['Address'];?></label></br>
<label>Contact: <?php echo $row['ContactNumber'];?></label></br>

<div id="divSenderMap">
<?php 
$url = "mapSender.html";
$_SESSION['SenderID'] = $row['ID'];
include $url ?>
</div>


<input type="button" id="btnSendReply" value="SEND"/>
<input type="button" id="btnCloseDiv" value="X" onclick="closeDiv()"/>
```

mapSender.html is supposed to return a map where the person is, the code is working on any other file/page, but it does not do it here. It is returning php and html codes but not javascript codes. What could be wrong?

Comment: Have you by any chance, named the PHP file with a ".html" extension? I'm a little confused as the details are fuzzy, but it's a possibility from what I can see

Comment: Oh, sorry, I just tried if it will work, some other file where I need to include maps were in .html extension and it's working just fine, in my mapSender.html file only have 
<script type="text/javascript">
 alert();</script>
this code right now, testing if it will work, and there's no alert box.

Answer (score 0):

As @MichaelLonghurst told it seems your file is named **mapSender.html**. So the server does not call PHP before return the HTML.

You should rename mapSender.html into mapSender.php.

Comment: I just tried if it will work, some other file where I need to include maps were in .html extension and it's working just fine, in my mapSender.html file only have <script type="text/javascript"> alert(); </script> this code right now, testing if it will work, and there's no alert box. I changed it back to .php extension now, and still no alert box.